# How to map network response into a C# class?

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization, tcpclient, networkstream

I'm trying to communicate with a server over TCP/IP protocol. Here is my method:

```
private bool SendTcpRequest<T>(T request, Settings settings)
    {
        try
        {
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient(settings.Url, settings.Port);

            byte[] data = null;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.ToString()))
                data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(request.ToString());
            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

            if (stream.CanWrite)
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            else
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (stream.CanRead)
            {
                byte[] myReadBuffer = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
                IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

                do
                {
                    var numberOfBytesRead = stream.Read(myReadBuffer, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);

                    responseMessage = new StringBuilder();
                    responseMessage.AppendFormat("{0}", Encoding.ASCII.GetString(myReadBuffer, 0, numberOfBytesRead));
                }
                while (stream.DataAvailable);
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
            stream.Close();
            client.Close();
            return true;
        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException e)
        {
            return false;
        }
        catch (SocketException e)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

The server will send response like bellow:

```
<TOPUPRESPONSE>
     <RESULT>00</RESULT> // status of the transaction
     <RESULTTEXT>transaction successful</RESULTTEXT> //description of the result code
     <TERMINALID>69500002</TERMINALID>
     <TXID>0803170919092</TXID>
     <PRODUCTID>XYZ</PRODUCTID>
</TOPUPRESPONSE>
```

Now I have a c# class for response, I'm wondering how I can map the network response to my class. I'm pretty new in this, I'm not even sure how my responseMessage will look like? Can anyone give some idea please?

Answer (score 2):

Create a class based on that repose if that's what your working with:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName="TOPUPRESPONSE")]
    public class TOPUPRESPONSE {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="RESULT")]
        public string RESULT { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="RESULTTEXT")]
        public string RESULTTEXT { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="TERMINALID")]
        public string TERMINALID { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="TXID")]
        public string TXID { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="PRODUCTID")]
        public string PRODUCTID { get; set; }
    }
```

Then just deserialize it to work with the data as a class:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TOPUPRESPONSE ));
MemoryStream memStream = new    MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(inputString));
msg resultingMessage = (TOPUPRESPONSE)serializer.Deserialize(memStream);
```

or use a StringReader:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TOPUPRESPONSE));
StringReader rdr = new StringReader(inputString);
msg resultingMessage = (TOPUPRESPONSE)serializer.Deserialize(rdr);
```